# jquery assign value to global variable on click

Tags: jquery

How to get the scenario_id assigned to the global variable..right now in the console it prints `empty string`. How to go about this

```
  var scenario_id = "";
  $('.edit_class').click(function() {

    scenario_id = $(this).attr('value');
  });

  console.log(scenario_id);
```

Comment: it should print an empty string not undefined

Comment: it is because the value of `scenario_id` is changed only after an `edit_class` is clicked. you are logging it before the value is changed. you need to move the console stmt to the callback method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `scenario_id` will only be assigned on a click event. Your `console.log()` is running after you've assigned the handler but *before* the user has clicked `edit_class`, so the value will be `undefined`. Try this to see the updated value of `scenario_id`:

```
var scenario_id = "";
$('.edit_class').click(function() {
    scenario_id = $(this).attr('value');
    console.log(scenario_id);
});
```

It may help you to read over the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/2165552) which explains javascript variable scoping.

Comment: But i want to assign it to global variable not in the function scope

Comment: By defining the variable in the global scope it will be global, regardless of where you set the value.